# PHP: gif to png

Tags: php, gd

How can I convert and save a gif image to PNG in PHP? I already tried a few ways but none of them worked. I can't do it manually because those images get generated at another site.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: The manual has all the answers, and it really just involves two functions: [`imagecreatefromgif`](http://php.net/imagecreatefromgif), [`imagepng`](http://php.net/imagepng).

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromgif.php

Comment: Googling `php gif to png` shows everything you need

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `imagecreatefromgif` <sup>[[docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromgif.php)]</sup> function to load a GIF, and then `imagepng` <sup>[[docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php)]</sup> function to output it as a PNG image. You should also send the header `Content-Type: image/png` to ensure it's properly interpreted by the browser.

```
<?php
$i = imagecreatefromgif("path or URL of file");
header("Content-Type: image/png");
imagepng($i);
?>
```

If you want to save it to a file, instead of sending it to the browser, do this instead:

```
<?php
$i = imagecreatefromgif("path or URL of file");
imagepng($i, "converted.png");
?>
```